# Why is my bash script terminating?

Tags: linux, bash, node.js

I have a node app running on my Linux hosting server.

Sometimes the app crashes and I need to restart it, so I log in and type these commands:

```
pkill node
cd public_html/n49900_dpndev
node server.js &
```

And the app runs again.

Now I would like to put this into a script so I simply need to start the script (or can execute it from a PHP script, for instance).

I created a file called "startnode":

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill node
cd public_html/n49900_dpndev
node server.js &
```

I changed the permissions with `chmod 755 startnode`.

But when I execute it with `./startnode` it responds with:

> Terminated

**What do I need to do so that the commands I type in manually also work in the bash script?**

Comment: Why don't you just make a systemd unit?

Comment: add a `-x` to your first line:
`#!/bin/bash -x`  
That will show your verbose/debug node and you can see where the terminated appears.  
Does node or server.js _require_ an interactive shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script name has "node" in the name and `pkill node` is probably killing it.

Using `pkill -x node` to kill only processes whose name is exactly "node" might be more to your liking. Or even `pkill -f -x "node server.js"` to kill the process with the exact full command line.

Answer (score 2):

`pkill` is killing every process launched with a program with a name containing the word `node` even you script

Rename you script to whatever name not containing the word `node`